Test not setup properly error in Jetpack Compose UI test using BDD (Cucumber)
I m trying to write a UI test using BDD + Compose but I keep getting the following error:

Test not setup properly. Use a ComposeTestRule in your test to be able to interact with composables

I have tried both createComposeRule and createAndroidComposeRule:
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class LoginSteps {
    @get:Rule
    val composeTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule<MainActivity>()

    @Given("^I am on the signup page$")
    fun I_am_on_the_signup_page() {
        // the following line produces the error:
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag("logo").assertIsDisplayed()
    }

    @When("^I click the login button$")
    fun when_I_click_login() {
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag("loginBtn").assertIsDisplayed().performClick()
    }

    @Then("^I should see the login page$")
    fun See_the_Sign_in_page() {
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag("LoginWelcomemsg").assertIsDisplayed()
    }
}

Full stacktrace:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Test not setup properly. Use a ComposeTestRule in your test to be able to interact with composables
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.ComposeRootRegistry_androidKt.ensureComposeRootRegistryIsSetUp(ComposeRootRegistry.android.kt:254)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.ComposeRootRegistry_androidKt.waitForComposeRoots(ComposeRootRegistry.android.kt:261)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment.waitForIdle(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:338)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment.access$waitForIdle(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:230)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidComposeUiTestEnvironment$AndroidTestOwner.getRoots(ComposeUiTest.android.kt:533)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.TestContext.getAllSemanticsNodes$ui_test_release(TestOwner.kt:86)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.SemanticsNodeInteraction.fetchSemanticsNodes$ui_test_release(SemanticsNodeInteraction.kt:63)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.SemanticsNodeInteraction.fetchSemanticsNodes$ui_test_release$default(SemanticsNodeInteraction.kt:56)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.AndroidAssertions_androidKt.checkIsDisplayed(AndroidAssertions.android.kt:29)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.AssertionsKt.isDisplayed(Assertions.kt:359)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.AssertionsKt.assertIsDisplayed(Assertions.kt:33)
    at uk.co.topcashback.topcashback.qa.steps.login.LoginSteps.I_am_on_the_dual_page(LoginSteps.kt:61)
    at ✽.I am on the dual page(file:/features/login.feature:4)


It appears you're trying to use the test rule from your steps class.  Instead, move this to your test class and try that.  Test rules belong in the test class.

Seems a similar answer was provided by someone else here too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78347141/465442

Try to add an empty compose test rule to you test (or base test) class and pass it to the constructor of your page object class.
For example:
open class TestClass {

    @get:Rule
    val composeTestRule = createEmptyComposeRule()

    private lateinit var loginPage: LoginPageObject

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        loginPage = LoginPageObject(composeTestRule)
    }

    @Test
    fun testLoginProcess() {
        loginPage.assertLogoIsDisplayed()
    }

}

class LoginPageObject(private val composeTestRule: ComposeTestRule) {
    fun assertLogoIsDisplayed() {
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag("logo").assertIsDisplayed()
    }
}


The main issue is that @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class) should be replaced by @WithJunitRule
The composeTestRule shouldn't be directly instantiated/created at your step classes to support multiple step classes.
The suggested way from https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-android is to create a separated class for your compose rule. Start with createAndroidComposeRule and switch to createEmptyComposeRule when different app start behaviour is needed.
@WithJunitRule
class ComposeRuleHolder {

    @get:Rule
    val composeRule = createAndroidComposeRule()
}

Then ComposeRuleHolder should be injected into your step classes.
// note: no annotation required here
class LoginSteps(val composeTestRule: ComposeTestRule) { ... }

Cucumber runner does detect when a step class needs some dependencies and will search for a dependency framework. If you don't use any dependency injection framework yet then just add cucumber-picocontainer as android test dependency.
